# Pipeline Python with if and else statement for two models

Tags: python, if-statement, machine-learning, pipeline, pmml

Assume I have trained two machine learning models both use random forest but one of them is for classification and the other is for prediction. I would like to do first the classification and if the output is 2 then the predication. I would like to use one pipeline for that (besides pipeline everything works well) to convert the model to PMML file. I am wondering as how to implement the pipeline for this(since there are two models per say and are separated with if and else statement) and ideally I would like to have one pipeline to do both.

For example I have something like this for each pipeline but do not know how to combine them with the if-else statement.

```
Pipe1 = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()),('classifier', RandomForestRegressor())])

Pipe2 = Pipeline([('classifier', RandomForestClassifier())])
```

After performing the prediction phase for the classification if the output is 2 then run the second pipeline.

Comment: @desertnaut, I added some more details. I have those two pipelines and looking for to combine them to only one pipeline but I do not know how to proceed. I know pipeline only works for transform and fit and no if else statement.

Comment: Why you feel you need to implement any if-then logic *inside* some pipeline? Why not just an external if-then, conditioned on the output of `Pipe2`?

Comment: Assume I want to have one PMML file then I need to have one pipeline. The overall plan is to have a PMML file.

Answer (score 0):

General idea - wrap the first estimator as transformer, and select the next model based on its transformation value. The wrapping is necessary, because according to Scikit-Learn conventions, a pipeline should not contain more than one model.

```
from sklego.meta import EstimatorTranformer
from sklearn2pmml.ensemble import SelectFirstClassifier
from sklearn2pmml.pipeline import PMMLPipeline

pipeline = PMMLPipeline([
  ("transformer", EstimatorTransformer(RandomForestClassifier())),
  ("estimator", SelectFirstClassifier([
    ("is_two", "X[0] == 2", RandomForestClassifier()),
    ("is_not_two", "True", RandomForestClassifier())
  ]))
])
```